# Delete an element from training_phrases object of dialogflow api

Tags: dialogflow-es

How to delete a training phrase element from the object “training_phrases” of dialogflow api?

Comment: Can you provide details of what you have done and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: if you want to delete a training phrase, you can do it in console. can you explain what do you want to achieve? maybe screenshots or code/log/error